# Using Android Test Filter (@SmallTest, @MediumTest, @LargeTest) for Local Unit Tests

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am trying to use the android support filters @SmallTest, @MediumTest, @LargeTest,... for local unit tests. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to filter them when invoking the unit test via gradle.

I found only invocation examples for instrumented tests.

Do you have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance

-- EDIT --
My plan is to introduce more annotations like 'externalTests' or 'benchmarking' which I can run out of my regular test scope (e.g. nightly or something). Another idea would be to filter the test directories in gradle config. But I think the annotation would be much nicer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found is [JUnit Categories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Categories). Via categories you can mark your tests with a specific interface and filter these in the gradle file.
I created an interface

```
package com.mypackage.testing.category;

public interface Benchmark {
    // this is just a marker interface
}
```

In the tests it can be used as follows

```
public class CategoryTest {

    @Test
    public void unitTest() {
        System.out.println("I am a unit test");
    }

    @Test
    @Category(Benchmark.class)
    public void benchmarkTest() {
        System.out.println("I am a benchmark test");
    }
}
```

Different categories can be filtered in the gradle file, e.g. with a gradle parameter `benchmark`

```
 android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            useJUnit()
            if (project.hasProperty("benchmark").booleanValue()) {
                options {
                    includeCategories 'com.mypackage.testing.category.Benchmark'
                }
            } else {
                options {
                    excludeCategories 'com.mypackage.testing.category.Benchmark'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```